# Jquery popup on mouse over of calendar control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I am using the Calendar control of ASP.NET. I need to display a pop-up form when I hover over a particular date in the Calendar control. This pop-up should display data from database.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an empty div:

```
<div id="popup"></div>
```

then bind an event to the calendar elements:

```
('li.calendar').hover(function(){
   //make an ajax call and populate the popup div with the data
   //easiest method is jquery.load(), but if you need more control use jquery.ajax();
   $("popup").load('path/to/page.asp',data,function(){
       $("popup").show();
   });


});
```

Look at [jquery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and [jquery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: can u explain here what is the meaning of path/to/page.asp and data ?

Comment: "path/to/page.asp" is the path to your asp page that serves the data, "data" can be omitted if you don't want to send anything to the asp page (as a POST request), if you have data to send, just create "var data = 'some data'" and post it to the asp page. You better read the links i provided, there are pretty simple examples there.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how asp name the date spans, check it, its very easy to detect 
after getting the selector 
user jQuery to add the event

```
jQuery('selector').hover(function(){ //or use mousemove
  getPopup(jQuery(this).text()); // just send any data to detect the date
}) ;
```

after that you'll need to make an AJAX request in the getPopup function

you may use

```
jQuery.get()//or jQuery.post()
__doPostBack()//if you have update panels 
//or any ajax technique xmlhttprequest,PM,...
```

in the response of the ajax request just draw the popup ...

hope this helps

examle getPopup function

```
function getPopup(date/*for example*/){
  jQuery.getScript('www.myWebsite.com/pageThatDrawsThePopup?date='+date);
  // getScript assuming that the return value is JS code the immediately draws the popup
  // ?date = date assuming that your page takes the date as query string and get the data from the database upon this field 
  //dont forget to change the url
 //very simple very easy ...  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a CSS class to the cell containing the date that should trigger the popup. You'll need to override the [DayRender event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender.aspx) to do this.

```
void myCalendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date.Day.ToString().EndsWith("7")){// Replace with your own condition
        e.Cell.CssClass+=   "specialCell"; //replace with your own custom css class name
    }
}
```

Then add some JavaScript (or Jquery) to trigger the pop-up. The JQuery ajax  functions provide the easiest way to get your data and populate the pop-up as per @user1225246's answer.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.specialCell').hover(function(){

        function(){//This will get called when you mouseover
            alert('put your JQuery AJAX code here.');
        },

        function(){
            alert('do any clean-up (e.g. hiding the popup if you need to) here.');
        }
    });
```

Comment: No problem. Please see my update - I added some basic JS to hold it all together.

Good luck.